# How do I use an external URL to pre-select a drop-down menu option?

Tags: html, url

Using a website's URL, I am trying to figure out how to pre-select an option from a drop down menu. I can't change anything about the webpage as it is auto-generated from the retailer. Unfortunately, I am not experienced in Java Script or JQuery, so I am hoping to use just the URL to select the option for me.

For example, if the URL is:

`https://mywebsite.com/`

How do I adjust the URL to automatically select `Product 8` from the drop down menu when I am presented with the following:

```
<div id="dynamic_option_id_1001" class="field">
    <label class="required">Product</label>
    <div class="control" style="position: relative;">
        <select name="options[1001]" id="select_1001" class="product-custom-option admin__control-select open-dd" validation="{"required":true}" title>
            <option value>-- Please Select --</option>
            <option value="10001" product-sku price="0.00">Product 1</option>
            <option value="10002" product-sku price="6.50">Product 2 +$6.50</option>
            <option value="10003" product-sku price="8.50">Product 3 +$8.50</option>
            <option value="10004" product-sku price="8.50">Product 4 +$8.50</option>
            <option value="10005" product-sku price="9.50">Product 5 +$9.50</option>
            <option value="10006" product-sku price="9.50">Product 6 +$9.50</option
            <option value="10007" product-sku price="9.50">Product 7 +$9.50</option>
            <option value="10008" product-sku price="37.00" disabled>Product 8 +$37.00 (out of stock)</option>    
        </select>
        <div class="dpo_dd_mask"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using the `/?` designation in the URL to try to select `Product 8`, but I don't think I am using it correctly. For example:

`https://mywebsite.com/?select_1001_product-custom-option=10008`

Any assistance would be awesome. Thank you! =)